# How to outsource PHP functions correctly in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin which extends the database with various tables.

For this I have the following code in my main.php file.
This also works so far. But I would like to write the code in another file to clean up a bit.

```
function install_tables()
{
  global $wpdb;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'test';
  $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
      id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      test varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      UNIQUE KEY id (id),
    ) $charset_collate;";
  require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
  dbDelta($sql);
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'install_tables');
```

However, the functions are apparently no longer called with include.
`include('install-plugin.php');`

With my other code it works, only not with the extension of the database.
What am I doing wrong here? I also tested it with **require** and **require_once**

Comment: You probably got the path wrong, I would guess. (Did require give you any errors?) [How to include PHP files in plugins the correct way](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/7398), https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories

Comment: Yes, I include many external files in this way and these are working

Comment: Have you tried it in the way explained under those links I gave you?